# Callback interface inheriting another interface

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inheritance, interface

I try to create a "modular" architecture for my WCF service. My HostFunctions (ServiceContracts) do work, but I can't apply the same scheme to my callback interfaces.

What I want to achieve:

```
public interface ICallback : ICallbackA, ICallbackB
{
} 

public interface ICallbackA 
{
    [OperationContract] 
    void MethodA(); 
}

public interface ICallbackB
{   
    [OperationContract]
    void MethodB();
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof (ICallback))]
public interface IHostFunctions : IFunctionsA
{
}
```

When I do this and create a proxy with SvcUtil.exe, I get only my HostFunctions with the ServiceContract attribute. My callback interface(s) are not included in the proxy. Here's an example of what it should look like: [Generated Proxy with callbacks](https://gist.github.com/Mythos94/44dfffc4a44c6b9414df)

My generated proxy looks the same except including the callback interface.
Also I can't/mustn't reference the Service's project in my Client's project.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Did you decorate `ICallback` with `[ServiceContract]`?

Comment: Nope I didn't. Do I have to? All tutorial I've found don't decorate it with `[ServiceContract]`

Comment: Perhaps not when you're dealing with callbacks.  Are you able to use the callbacks?

Comment: Adding `[ServiceContract]` to `ICallback` and the other interfaces (A and B) does not work. I still don't get the callback interface into the proxy.

Comment: Only the HostFunctions from `IHostFunctions` (including `IFunctionsA`) are included in the proxy.